# Using Arrays in a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript class defined as shown here:

```
function Item() { 
  this.init(); 
} 

Item.prototype = { 
  id: null, 
  name: '', 
  description: '', 
  init: function () { 
    this.id = "1"; 
  } 
};
```

I want to add a property called "logs". I want this property to be an array of other class entities. How do I define this kind of array as a property on my Item class? How do I add entities to that array? Originally, I thought I could add "this.logs = {};" in my init function. Then in my code elsewhere, I tried the following:

```
Item i = new Item();
i.logs.push(NewLog());
```

However, the push function through an error that says: "Cannot call method 'push' of undefined"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logs` is not initialized yet. Add it in the constructor (not to the prototype, because the array would then be shared by all instances of `Item`):

```
function Item() { 
  this.init();
  this.logs = []; // Not {}:   [] is equivalent to new Array(), and
}                 //           {} is equivalent to new Object() (not an array)
```

Also, JavaScript != Java.

```
var i = new Item() // instead of Item i = new Item();
```

Comment: How do I add items to the array then? Once "i" is created, how do I "push" items onto the array?

Comment: @JQueryMobile You said that you wanted to add elements to the `logs` array (which is a property of the "class instance"). Use `i.logs.push(NewLog());`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Item.prototype = { 
  id: null, 
  name: '', 
  description: '', 
  init: function () { 
    this.id = "1"; 
  },
  push: Array.prototype.push 
};
```